# Bash: Strip trailing linebreak from output

Tags: bash, newline, line-breaks

When I execute commands in Bash (or to be specific, `wc -l < log.txt`), the output contains a linebreak after it. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: [Similar question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140727)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

**If your expected output is a single line**, you can simply remove all newline characters from the output. It would not be uncommon to pipe to the `tr` utility, or to Perl if preferred:

```
wc -l < log.txt | tr -d '\n'

wc -l < log.txt | perl -pe 'chomp'
```

You can also use command substitution to remove the trailing newline:

```
echo -n "$(wc -l < log.txt)"

printf "%s" "$(wc -l < log.txt)"
```

---

**If your expected output may contain multiple lines**, you have another decision to make:

If you want to remove MULTIPLE newline characters from the end of the file, again use cmd substitution:

```
printf "%s" "$(< log.txt)"
```

If you want to strictly remove THE LAST newline character from a file, use Perl:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if eof' log.txt
```

---

Note that if you are certain you have a trailing newline character you want to remove, you can use `head` from GNU coreutils to select everything except the last byte. This should be quite quick:

```
head -c -1 log.txt
```

Also, for completeness, you can quickly check where your newline (or other special) characters are in your file using `cat` and the 'show-all' flag `-A`. The dollar sign character will indicate the end of each line:

```
cat -A log.txt
```

Comment: This strips ALL newlines from the output, not just the trailing newline as the title asks.

Comment: @CodyA.Ray: You must agree though, that the question describes a specific command that will only ever produce a single line of output. I have, however, updated my answer to suit the more general case. HTH.

Comment: This would be better if the short options were replaced with long options. The long options teach as well as function e.g. `tr --delete '\n'`.

Comment: I also did `| tr -d '\r'`

Comment: It's worth noting that the cmd substitution solution might lead to an overlong line if the file is very big.

Comment: My up-vote is for the `head -c ... ` version -- Because I can _now_ feed commands to the clipboard and preserve formatting, but for the last `\n`.  Eg.:  `alias clip="head -c -1 | xclip -selection clipboard"`, not too shabby.  Now when you pipe `ls -l | clip` ... All that wonderful output goes to the X-Server `clipboard` without a terminating `\n`.  Ergo ... I can paste that into my next command, _just so_.  Many thanks!

Comment: Any reason for using `head -c -1` instead of `head -n -1`, given that we know that it's a newline?

Comment: @lindhe `head -n -1` removes the last line including its text and still leaves the previous EOL char in the output, so it doesn't do the same thing as `head -c -1`

Comment: `head -c -1` was what I needed since it is in the middle of a pipeline, perfect thanks

Answer (score 96):

One way:

```
wc -l < log.txt | xargs echo -n
```

Comment: Better: `echo -n \`wc -l log.txt\``

Comment: Why is doing command execution in backticks better than using a pipe?

Comment: These will not only remove the trailing newlines, but also squeeze any consecutive whitespaces (more precisely, as defined by `IFS`) to one space. Example: `echo "a  b" | xargs echo -n`; `echo -n $(echo "a  b")`. This may or may not be a problem for the use case.

Comment: Worse, if the output begins with `-e`, it will be interpreted as the option to `echo`. It's always safer to use `printf '%s'`.

Comment: `xargs` is very slow on my system (and I suspect it is on other systems too), so `printf '%s' $(wc -l log.txt)` might be faster, since `printf` is usually a builtin (Also because there is no information redirection). Never use backticks, they have been deprecated in newer POSIX versions and have numerous drawbacks.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to remove **only the last newline**, pipe through:

```
sed -z '$ s/\n$//'
```

`sed` won't add a `\0` to then end of the stream if the delimiter is set to `NUL` via `-z`, whereas to create a POSIX text file (defined to end in a `\n`), it will always output a final `\n` without `-z`.

Eg:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//'; echo tender
foo
bartender
```

And to prove no `NUL` added:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f0a 6261 72                        foo.bar
```

---

To **remove multiple trailing newlines**, pipe through:

```
sed -Ez '$ s/\n+$//'
```

Comment: I suppose this is a GNU extension, Mac `sed` doesn't provide `-z`.

Comment: You can install gnu version of sed on mac, as `gsed` and use it, by [doing what it says here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30003570/26510)

Comment: Can someone explain what the `$ ` in the beginning of the sed expression does?

Comment: If I interpret it correctly, the `$` is for selecting the last line and thus to avoid executing the `sed` command on all lines. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses

Answer (score 24):

There is also direct support for white space removal in [Bash variable substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
testvar=$(wc -l < log.txt)
trailing_space_removed=${testvar%%[[:space:]]}
leading_space_removed=${testvar##[[:space:]]}
```

Comment: You can also use `trailing_linebreak_removed=${testvar%?}`

Comment: Note that if you are using command substitution then you don't need to do anything to remove trailing newlines.  Bash already does that as part of command substitution: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Answer (score 14):

If you want to print output of anything in Bash without end of line, you echo it with the `-n` switch.

If you have it in a variable already, then echo it with the [trailing newline](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) cropped:

```
$ testvar=$(wc -l < log.txt)
$ echo -n $testvar
```

Or you can do it in one line, instead:

```
$ echo -n $(wc -l < log.txt)
```

Comment: The variable is technically unnecessary. `echo -n $(wc -l < log.txt)` has the same effect.

Answer (score 11):

[printf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) already crops the trailing newline for you:

```
$ printf '%s' $(wc -l < log.txt)
```

Detail:

- printf will print your content in place of the `%s` string place holder.
- If you do not tell it to print a newline (`%s\n`), it won't.

Comment: If you put double quotes around the command like `"$(command)"`, the internal newlines will be preserved -- and only the *trailing* newline will be removed.  The shell is doing all the work here -- `printf` is just a way to direct the results of command substitution back to `stdout`.

Comment: It's not printf that's stripping the new line here, it's the shell that's doing it with the `$( )` construct. Here's proof: `printf "%s" "$(perl -e 'print "\n"')"`

Comment: Again, it's worth noting that the resulting command line might become too long.

Comment: This is a convenient solution with @nobar's suggestion: `$ printf '%s' "$(wc -l < log.txt)"`

Answer (score 10):

If you assign its output to a variable, `bash` automatically strips whitespace:

```
linecount=`wc -l < log.txt`
```

Comment: Trailing newlines are stripped, to be exact. It's the command substitution that removes them, not the variable assignment.

Comment: I've seen in Cygwin bash the trailing whitespace not removed when using $(cmd /c echo %VAR%). In this case I've had to use ${var%%[[:space:]]}.

Comment: Note: it is not the variable assignment, but the expression expansion that removes newlines.

Answer (score 9):

Adding this for my reference more than anything else ^_^

You can also strip a new line from the output using the bash expansion magic

```
VAR=$'helloworld\n'

CLEANED="${VAR%$'\n'}"

echo "${CLEANED}"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Awk:**

```
awk -v ORS="" '1' log.txt
```

**Explanation:**

1. -v assignment for ORS
2. ORS - output record separator set to blank. This will replace new line (Input record separator) with ""

Comment: -1 (though I did not actually press the button for it since I would only be allowed to change it once). This removes *all* newlines, not just any leading or trailing ones.