# `echo -n` prints nothing

Tags: bash, echo, newline

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524308/bash-remove-linebreak-after-result) to strip the newline from a string, but I've encountered a problem on one host.

For some reason, `/bin/echo -n foo` prints nothing on that host. I have no idea why that host behaves oddly. `/bin/echo foo` works fine. It's not the terminal, since `echo -n foo > /tmp/bar` also shows nothing.

`/bin/echo --help` says that is *should* work:

```
Usage: /bin/echo [OPTION]... [STRING]...
Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

  -n             do not output the trailing newline
  -e             enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -E             disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

% /bin/echo --version
echo (GNU coreutils) 5.97
```

What can possibly cause this not to work? Could there be some strange buffering in this bash-shell?

Comment: You could also use `printf`.

Comment: Yes. And I got it working with `tr -d '\n'`. But I am wondering what's wrong with `echo` on that host.

Comment: Who knows?  BTW, `echo` is a bash builtin, too.  Not sure which one you're using.

Comment: Are you sure it prints nothing? Perhaps the output is being overwritten by your shell prompt. Try `/bin/echo -n foo | wc`. (I know you said that `echo -n foo > /tmp/bar` shows nothing; did you check that by running `cat /tmp/bar`?)

Comment: @keith-thompson: Yes, I tried `cat`, but I didn't try `wc`. Good idea! The problem is the terminal, not `echo`. Very strange. Might be my `LS_COLORS` or `INPUTRC`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on information in comments, it appears that `/bin/echo -n foo` is producing the expected output, but it's being overwritten by your next shell prompt. (Most likely it's your shell, not your terminal settings.)

You can demonstrate this by running

```
/bin/echo -n foo | wc
```

which should produce this output:

```
  0       1       3
```

You can also try this:

```
/bin/echo -n foo ; sleep 5
```

This will delay your next shell prompt for 5 seconds, so you can see the output before it's overwritten.

(What shell are you using? What's the value of `$PS1`?)

Comment: @cdunn2001: Again, what shell are you using? (You mention bash in your question, but that looks like zsh syntax.)

Comment: Probably zsh. But I do not have a homedir on that host.

Comment: @cdunn2001: You can still tell what shell you're using, for example `echo $ZSH_VERSION`. Did you try my suggestions? (I wonder *why* you don't have a home directory, but it's probably not relevant.)

Comment: Yes, your sleep suggestion proves that you are right. And ZSH_VERSION is `4.2.6`.