# Avoid "enter" when pasting xsel / xclip

Tags: linux, clipboard, piping, xclip

This is somewhat simple, I presume, but still I cannot figure out how to do it. I have the following function defined:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M | xclip -selection c
```

which gets a timestamp and puts it into the clipboard. I mainly want to use this to name files, so I can, for example, go

```
vi file_2016-02-16_20:10_somemorethings.txt
```

but when I paste the date in the terminal (with control+shift+V) it already enters the command, so I never get the chance to type `_somemorethings.txt`. In other words, the last character that `xclip` saves is the Enter key. This happens everytime I pipe something to `xclip` or `xsel`, not only with the function defined above.

I know this sounds like something unimportant, but it would really improve productivity is this little issue could be fixed.

I have tried several options with both `xclip` and `xsel` and nothing seems to overcome this. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: You could use `tr` for example  `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M  | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection c`  See this question for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524308/bash-strip-trailing-linebreak-from-output

Comment: @edi9999 I can't believe I didn't think of that. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use tr, for example

```
date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection c
```

See this question for different ways to achieve it: [Bash: Strip trailing linebreak from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524308/)

Answer (score 2):

Just a note for anyone who comes here in the future, the command

```sh
date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M | xclip -rmlastnl -selection c
```

will do the job now.