# After grep values should be come side by side instead of line by line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I am grepping the one API what ever the values is comming I am passing those list values into one file in that file all the values is showing line by line  may I know how can I get side by side . May I know is there any command for that .

```
curl -u admin:xxxx -X GET https://raju.jfrog.io/raju/api/repositories -H "application/json" | grep "key" | grep "raju" | awk '{print $3}'
```

```
"ansiraju",
"ansiraju-testing",
"raju-newrepo",
"raju-test",
"rajujlm",
"rajujlm1234",
"rajujlmk",
"rajujlmmn",
"rajujlmmnkm",
"rajujlmm",
```

May I know how can I get there values side by side like below

`"ansiraju", "ansiraju-testing", "raju-newrepo"` ..etc like that . Can any one help me on this

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools for parsing JSON, use a syntax-aware tool like [tag:jq].

Comment: Add `ORS=" "` at the end, right after `awk '{print $3}'`. You may remove your greps and use `awk '/key/ && /raju/{print $3}' ORS=" "`

Answer (score 1):

You can try piping the output through `tr` with arguments like this `tr '\n\t' ', '`. Here the translation is done by replacing `'\n'`and `'\t'` with `','` and `' '`.

```
curl -u admin:xxxx -X GET https://raju.jfrog.io/raju/api/repositories -H "application/json" | grep "key" | grep "raju" | awk '{print $3}' | tr '\n\t' ', '
```

Reference: [Bash: Strip trailing linebreak from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524308/bash-strip-trailing-linebreak-from-output)

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper tools, but if you can not do that, you can collect all commands in on tool like `awk`

```
your command | awk '/key/ && /raju/ {printf "%s",$3} END {print}'

curl -u admin:xxxx -X GET https://raju.jfrog.io/raju/api/repositories -H "application/json" | awk '/key/ && /raju/ {printf "%s",$3} END {print}'
"ansiraju","ansiraju-testing","raju-newrepo",
```

It will search for both `key` and `raju` at the same time print therd field with correct formatting.