# Replacing dates in bash script using sed: phantom newline error

Tags: regex, bash, sed

So I'm trying to do a simple regex replacement of a date in the metadata of a document using sed from bash.  For example, suppose I have input file `test.md` containing:

```
---
title: "I am a file"
date: December 1, 2021
---

Loren ipsum blah blah blah
```

I'd like to be able to run a bash script on December 29 and get an output file

```
---
title: "I am a file"
date: December 29, 2021
---

Loren ipsum blah blah blah
```

So here's my first try:

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +'%B %d, %Y')
STARTBIT="date: "

FULLDATE="$STARTBIT$TODAY"

REGEX="s/date:\s.*\n/$FULLDATE/"

echo $REGEX # to make sure I'm getting what I think I'm getting

sed  -e $REGEX < test.md > output.md
```

but I get the following output:

```
s/date:\s.*\n/date: December 29, 2021/
sed: 1: "s/date:\s.*\n/date:
": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

so this is a bit confusing, the first line is my echoed pattern, and I definitely don't see any newlines in it on the command line.  Nor am I sure quite where newlines would supposedly be??

So then I thought, ok, maybe the newline is appended to the end of one of the variables, and for some reason is made invisible due to some bash silliness when I echo it.  So based on [this prior SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19857996/4386239), I just went in and stripped newlines from the end of everything just to make sure.  Viz:

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +'%B %d, %Y')
STARTBIT="date: "
CLEANSTARTBIT=${STARTBIT%%[[:space:]]}
CLEANTODAY=${TODAY%%[[:space:]]}

FULLDATE="$STARTBIT$TODAY"
CLEANFULLDATE=${FULLDATE%%[[:space:]]}

REGEX="s/date:\s.*\n/$CLEANFULLDATE/"
CLEANREGEX=${REGEX%%[[:space:]]}

echo $CLEANREGEX

sed  -e $CLEANREGEX < test.md > output.md
```

and I'm **still** getting exactly the same output.  But now I'm really stumped.  There can't possibly be newlines sneaking in here...

Help??

Bonus possible issues:

1. I'm using the version of sed that shipped with macOS.  Heaven only knows what version.  Maybe I should try getting my hands on GNU sed??
2. I don't really know what flavor of regex sed uses, or indeed how sed works at all... I basically just copied the regex over from the one I was using in a python script since forever, for learning purposes/because I'm sick of calling out to python for this bit of basic text processing that I do all the time.  Hah, but I actually know python regex...

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. As it will point out: _Always_ quote your expansions. `"$REGEX"`, not `$REGEX`. (Also, while it _won't_ point this out, you shouldn't use all-caps names for your own variables; POSIX reserves that namespace for variables that change or reflect operation of the shell and others standard-defined tools).

Comment: ...that naming convention is given at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read it keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any preexisting environment variable by the same name, so you can't be 100% sure you're complying with the standard for environment variables without _also_ complying with it for shell variables.

Comment: Also, `\s` isn't guaranteed to work in `sed` _at all_. It's a PCRE extension; `sed` only guarantees support for the BRE regex syntax, or in some cases (with `-E` on BSD sed or `-r` on GNU sed) ERE. Some common operating systems _do_ add `\s` support to their versions of `sed`, but it's not reliable/portable behavior; use `[[:space:]]` instead to work with all standard-compliant implementations.

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions for an introduction on POSIX BRE, or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions re: ERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: you need to double-quote your variable references (e.g. `echo "$REGEX"` instead of `echo $REGEX`). Without the double-quotes, the variable's value will be split into "words", and any words that look like filename wildcards will be expanded into a list of matching files. You almost never want either of these things to happen, so you should almost always double-quote variable references. In particular, this command:

```
sed  -e $REGEX < test.md > output.md
```

Expands to something like:

```
sed -e s/date:\s.*\n/date: December 29, 2021/
```

...and "`s/date:\s.*\n/date:`", "`December`", "`29,`", and "`2021/`" are all treated as completely separate arguments to `sed`. The error message is misleading; the real error is that the first one is an incomplete `sed` command.

(If you happened to have any files matching `s/date:\s.*\n/date` -- unlikely, but technically possible -- things would get even sillier.)

The second problem is that, as you guessed, your regex is in the wrong syntax dialect. The version that comes with macOS doesn't support the `\s` shorthand, so use `[[:space:]]` instead. Also, using `\n` to match the end of line is invalid in any flavor of `sed`; use `$` instead (but you need to escape it, since it's in double-quotes and you don't want it to initiate some expansion rule):

```
REGEX="s/date:[[:space:]].*\$/$FULLDATE/"
```

Technically, you don't need the `$` either. Regex matching is greedy, so if it *can* match to the end of the line -- and it can -- it *will* match to the end of the line.

But it'd be a good idea to add `^` at the beginning of the pattern, to anchor it to the beginning of a line. Otherwise, it'll match "date: " anywhere in a line.

Third, I'd recommend switching to lower- or mixed-case variable names. There are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those it can have weird effects.

Final note: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out a lot of common scripting mistakes (such as failing to double-quote).