# Why m i not getting expected result of python --version?

Tags: python, linux, shell, version

In linux Debian9, I want comma seperated output of python3 and python2

I am writing this command:

```
echo $(python3 --version),$(python2 --version)
```

Output should be like this:

```
Python 3.7.3,Python 2.7.16
```

But I am getting output:

```
Python 2.7.16
Python 3.7.3,
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `python --version` outputs the Python version and a newline. If you don't want it, you'd have to strip the trailing newline.

Comment: [Bash: Strip trailing linebreak from output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524308/3890632) perhaps

Comment: Subshells are executed from right to left. `python3 --version | tr "\n" ","; python2 --version` will do the job.

Comment: @RichardNeumann understood the problem exactly, and your solution is also giving required string, but it I m looking for more simplest way. otherwise your answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach to do this:

```
echo $(python3 --version),$(python --version 2>&1)
```