# Bash command execution produces unwanted newline output

Tags: bash

Ordinarily, running a command as `$(command)` discards any trailing newlines produced by `command`. However, when I run this command:

```
output=$(kcadm get users)
```

I always get a newline echoed. Why, and how can I get rid of it? It doesn't make any difference if I do this, or an equivalent:

```
output=$(kcadm get users) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

`kcadm` is an alias to a shell script, which runs Java and produces JSON output. If I run the script directly, I can always completely suppress any output from it (`kcadm get users > /dev/null 2>&1`), but I of course need to record the output for analysis.

**EDIT**

Before anyone else jumps in with a close vote, please: the bash manual says that "trailing newlines are deleted" in `$()` command substitution. The suggested answer is not, AFAICT, relevant.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**

The suggested answer is for an entirely different question, and simply handles obvious cases where a substitution on the output removes a newline. This question is about a situation where the newline shouldn't have happened in the first place, and what *caused* it. This really should have been obvious to the close voters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: Strip trailing linebreak from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524308/bash-strip-trailing-linebreak-from-output)

Comment: Regarding my close vote, have you tried the solution provided in the duplicate ? It should still address your core issue

Comment: Last thing : does your alias spawn a sub process or writes something to stderr ?

Comment: @markp-fuso - yes, that was it, thanks - if you want to answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- when OP says *`I always get a newline echoed`*, this is in reference to the output from `output=$(kcadm get users)` and *not* the result of `echo "$output"`

Without more debugging details I'm going to *guess* that `kcadm` is sending a single blank line to stderr.

If this is the case then the stderr output is not captured by OP's current command - `output=$(kcadm get users)` - but rather passed to the terminal.

A simple test/fix would be to redirect `kcadm`'s stderr to stdout, eg:

```
output=$(kcadm get users 2>&1)
```